# Add dataframe to list of dataframes -pyspark

Tags: list, dataframe, pyspark

I have created a list of dataframes and now want to add another dataframe in order to union this list afterwards.

```
df_list = [spark.createDataFrame([("3", "4")], db_tables_schema), spark.createDataFrame([("1", "2")], db_tables_schema), spark.createDataFrame([("7", "4")], db_tables_schema)]

df_list = df_list.append([spark.createDataFrame([("7", "4")], db_tables_schema)])

#Reduce to one df
df_complete = reduce(DataFrame.union, df_list)
```

I thought that with .append one could easily add the element, however if I do so a "NoneType" Element is being created - so basically my list isn´t existing anymore.
What´s the matter here. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful, you are using `append` function and it adds an item to a list inplace. This function returns `None`, so if you assign to `df_list` the return of `df_list.append` it is the same as : `df_list = None`.
Just do it like this:

```py
df_list.append(my_element)
```

Secondly, you are trying to append a list of item(s), if you do it with `append` your list will look like this:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_list.append([4])
print(my_list)  # [1, 2, 3, [4]]
my_list.append([5, 6])
print(my_list)  # [1, 2, 3, [4], [5, 6]]
```

You should use `extend` instead:

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
my_list.extend([4])
print(my_list)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
my_list.extend([5, 6])
print(my_list)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```